# openssl decryption works even with modified key

Tags: linux, encryption, openssl, hex

I executed the below command and generated a random key

> openssl rand -hex 45

and it generated me

`524ec7a76ad9140087232b8e278c03d4bc121fdfd0e4f13a6bd16959a81e2d289b5edcf0848b435fc201fc4c1c`

I then encrypted me file with Open ssl using this. When i tried to decrypt i just changed last two characters like this

`524ec7a76ad9140087232b8e278c03d4bc121fdfd0e4f13a6bd16959a81e2d289b5edcf0848b435fc201fc4c2d`

and now when it tried to decrypt, it still works and decrypt the file... what could be wrong ? Below is my decrypt command

`export my_key=524ec7a76ad9140087232b8e278c03d4bc121fdfd0e4f13a6bd16959a81e2d289b5edcf0848b435fc201fc4c2d`

> openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -d -in my-secret-encrypted.enc -K $my_key -iv 9 > my-secret.txt

Comment: With -K a hex encoded key is specified. This key must be 32 bytes large for AES-256, i.e. it must consist of 64 hex digits. Your key is 45 bytes / 90 hex digits large. I guess that only the first 32 bytes / hex digits are taken into account, so changing the last byte / the last two hex digits has no effect.

Comment: Yes, OpenSSL: drops bytes if they are larger than the AES key sizes.